# How can i add fixed value donation paypal if no business account?

Tags: paypal

How can i add fixed value donation paypal if no business account, all i have is a button id, i'd like to add fixed amount when a user clicks on an image. Any ideeas how to do it?

Comment: What have you tried ? Any code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a URL like this

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donations&business=YOUR_EMAIL_ACCOUNT&currency_code=USD&amount=YOUR_FIXED_AMOUNT

This will take user to the Donation page with amount filled in.

Also, you can do the same here - paypal.com/donate/buttons